# BroadcastReceiver object only uses initial values, why?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, broadcastreceiver

Hi I'm trying to run a code which has one activity and a BroadcastReceiver which runs when new message comes and yes it's run clearly but I have a problem with  BroadcastReceiver object !

It's part of MainActivity CLASS  :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


   private IncomingSms checkAndDo; //=> OBJECT 

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       checkAndDo= new IncomingSms(); 
       checkAndDo.setProgramState(210); // program state is a variable
       checkAndDo.getProgramState(this); // Toast output  : " >>>210  "

       ....
```

But problem starts when a new message comes and onReceived() called ! IncommingSms class :

public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
private int programState=110; // Which state we are ?  110=> white / 111=> off / 210=>black ...     


public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


    this.getProgramState(context);  
     // This method called again but  toast output is : ">>>110" 
     // which is initial value !?

    AND .... 

  }



public void setProgramState(int status) {

    this.programState=status;

}


public void getProgramState( Context context) {


     Toast.makeText(context, ">>>"+this.programState , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

question : I'm not sure why it happens but onReceive() uses only the initial value which is so bad . ANY Idea?

Comment: How do you register your BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @Leog : With manifest if it's what you asked ; Like this :

Comment: <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms">   
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

Comment: Should I  register it Programmatically ?

Comment: @Germany21: instead of accessing variable by creating an object of `IncomingSms` Use `SharedPreferences` to share data between both components

Comment: There are 2 big list of strings too  , but maybe I use that way tanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> this.getProgramState(context);  
>  // This method called again but  toast output is : ">>>110" 
>  // which is initial value !?
> ```

You met that problem because you registered your BroadcastReceiver in the manifest. So Android will create a new BroadcastReceiver and pass the sms broadcast to it.

If you would like to get the state you set in your program, you must register your BroadcastReceiver in your Activity.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
registerReceiver(checkAndDo, filter);
```

Comment: I'm going to test it , Tanx .  please stay online . TANX

Answer (score 0):

using Intent data instead bundle

```
Intent(ContextHolder.applicationContext!!, NotificationDeleteReceiver::class.java).setData(conversation.conversationId.toUri())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).